# Changing Web.Config in ISAPI folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, windows-2003-webserver

I need to give access to another account on our production server's which is being used by clients at the momemnt.

Would it cause any trouble if I add another user to web.config or do I need downtime ?

Also does changing Web.Config in ISAPI (web services) folder requires IIS reset or Application pool reset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No restart is required, IIS will automatically detect that the web.config file has change and trigger an app pool recycle and read the new values. This will clear session and cache variables though so it will affect logged in people etc...